# Blur in default modal of React Native

Tags: react-native, blur

I would like to blur the background of my screen when the default modal opens.

I found this library for blur https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-blur

Has anyone achieved that?

I don't find solutions with just a background color on modal.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. This works  "react-native": "0.57.8", "react-native-blur": "^3.2.2"

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BlurView } from 'react-native-blur';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  findNodeHandle,
  Platform,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  title: {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 15,
  },
  absolute: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
});

export default class MyBlurredComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { viewRef: null };
  }

  onViewLoaded() {
    this.setState({ viewRef: findNodeHandle(this.viewRef) });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View
          style={[
            styles.blurredView,
          ]}
          ref={(viewRef) => { this.viewRef = viewRef; }}
          onLayout={() => { this.onViewLoaded(); }}
        >

         <Modal visible={true} animationType="fade" transparent={true} onRequestClose={() => console.log('closed')}>
            <View>
              <Text>Text</Text>
            </View>
         </Modal>


        </View>
        {
          this.state.viewRef && <BlurView
            style={styles.absolute}
            viewRef={this.state.viewRef}
            blurType="light"
            blurAmount={10}
          />
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it work on android ? My android app crashed with blur component

Comment: @ViktorHardubej this library is broken when you use multiple blur view in android

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to use any library to achieve this blur effect .Below is code that blurs Background Image when Modal is open.

```
{/*blurRadius is initially 0 and 4 when modal active more the blurradius more is blur effect of image*/}

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  Modal,
  Button,
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isVisible: false,
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground
        style={styles.container}
        blurRadius={this.state.isVisible ? 4 : 0}
        source={require('./bgimage.jpeg')}>
        <Modal
          animationType={'fade'}
          transparent={true}
          visible={this.state.isVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            console.log('Modal has been closed.');
          }}>
          <View style={styles.modal}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Modal is open!</Text>
            <Button
              title="Click To Close Modal"
              onPress={() => {
                this.setState({ isVisible: !this.state.isVisible });
              }}
            />
          </View>
        </Modal>

        <Button
          title="Click To Open Modal"
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({ isVisible: true });
          }}
        />
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
  },
  modal: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#606070',
    margin: 50,
  },
  text: {
    color: '#3f2949',
    marginTop: 10,
  },
});
```

Comment: Great solution, but wondering how to fix the blur effect on content inside the modal.
For example, https://snack.expo.io/BJEMKctIV

Comment: Can you please elaborate and let me know what exactly you want in screen.

Comment: So the above example will create the texts (the content inside the modal) blury too, I would like the overly to be blury not the content too.

Comment: I agree with @SubhenduKundu. Even though it is a nice solution I don't like the blurry content inside modal. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: Also what happens when i need to blur whichever background I have at that time? It doesn't need to be an image for background!

Comment: Found this library [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-blur-overlay) .This blurs normal view.Have a look at it.

Comment: Ahh, I thought the idea about your solution was not to use a library. Well, thanks anyway :)

Comment: yes i didnt wanted to use library but as solution found this will try to come up with customised example

Answer (score 0):

you should try this one

```
<Modal animationType="slide" transparent={true} visible={modalVisible}>
          <ImageBackground style={styles.centeredView} source={{uri: `${env.AssetsBaseURL}/assets/images/mandir-bg-blur.png`}}>
            <View style={styles.modalView}>
               //your view
            </View>
          </ImageBackground>
        </Modal>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     
    centeredView: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      position:"relative"
    },
    modalView: {
      width:"100%",
      position:"absolute",
      bottom:0,
      backgroundColor: "white",
      borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
      borderTopRightRadius: 20,
       
      shadowColor: "#000",
      shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 2
      },
      shadowOpacity: 0.25,
      shadowRadius: 4,
      elevation: 5
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: I think the image that you're using here matters... Can you include that asset (mandir-bg-blur.png) in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Putting the `BlurView` component directly inside the `Modal` and giving it the below styles fixed it for me. You should note, however, that intensity of the blur only affects iOS, Android has a fixed blur effect regardless of the `intensity` prop.

```
return (
    <View style={styles.mainWrap}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="default" />

      <View style={styles.contentWrap}>
        <Image
          style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
          source={{ uri: "https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png" }}
        />
        <Text>{`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum facilisis arcu vitae odio volutpat, non efficitur metus congue. Donec porttitor eu nibh a viverra. Vestibulum efficitur ex eu enim elementum, feugiat vulputate turpis efficitur. Suspendisse id enim tempor, malesuada velit eget, ultrices nunc. Suspendisse lorem velit, maximus a sem et, consectetur aliquam ligula. Morbi mauris justo, faucibus sit amet iaculis at, finibus non erat. Suspendisse aliquet augue ex, at efficitur purus tincidunt sit amet. Vestibulum faucibus leo eget odio eleifend, ut facilisis eros euismod. Duis sit amet est felis. Fusce ullamcorper diam et urna facilisis, imperdiet dignissim arcu sagittis. Integer sed lacus tortor. Ut vel mauris vitae magna consectetur suscipit sit amet at nisi.`}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            this.launchModal(true);
          }}
        >
          <Text>{`Launch modal`}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <Modal
        visible={this.state.modalVisible}
        transparent={true}
        animationType="fade"
      >
        <BlurView blurType="light" style={styles.contentWrap}>
          <Image
            style={{ width: 300, height: 150 }}
            source={{
              uri: "http://facebook.github.io/origami/public/images/blog-hero.jpg",
            }}
          />

          <Text>{`This is the modal!`}</Text>

          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              this.launchModal(false);
            }}
          >
            <Text>{`Close modal`}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </BlurView>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
```

Answer (score -2):

just add `backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'` to the style of (style.modal) container view

Comment: That adds a slightly transparent black background without any blur, doesn't answer the question